# How to update values for specific keys in dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a dictionary by using this:

```
a = dict.fromkeys([round(x*0.1,1) for x in range(10)], [0,0])
```

it will give me the following results:

```
>>> a
{0.0: [0, 0], 0.5: [0, 0], 0.2: [0, 0], 0.4: [0, 0], 0.8: [0, 0], 0.6: [0, 0], 0.3: [0, 0], 0.1: [0, 0], 0.9: [0, 0], 0.7: [0, 0]}
```

I only want to update the second value for key=0.5, for example. I was using the following code:

```
a[0.5][1]=a[0.5][1]+10
```

However, it turns out that it updated all second values for all keys.

```
>>> a
{0.0: [0, 10], 0.5: [0, 10], 0.2: [0, 10], 0.4: [0, 10], 0.8: [0, 10], 0.6: [0, 10], 0.3: [0, 10], 0.1: [0, 10], 0.9: [0, 10], 0.7: [0, 10]}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do that?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the full code, there's something else going on there.

Comment: did you initialize it as `[0, 0] * 10` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `dict.fromkeys` with a mutable value, it simply copies the reference to the same list object to all the keys. So, changing any one the reference is going to affect all the lists.

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys('abcdef', [])
>>> [id(x) for x in d.values()]
[164654156, 164654156, 164654156, 164654156, 164654156, 164654156]
```

Use a `dict comprehension` instead:

```
>>> d = {k:[] for k in  'abcdef'}
>>> [id(x) for x in d.values()]
[164621484, 164653580, 164331340, 164653804, 164653900, 164653836]
```

For your code it is going to be:

```
a = {round(x*0.1,1): [0, 0] for _ in range(10)}
```

Comment: I might seem like being picky, but `it simply copies the same list object to all the keys` - shouldn't this read `it simply copies the reference to the same list object to all the keys`?

Comment: @kroolik Your version looks good, I've updated my answer. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Very nice explanation! That helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That because you used the same list for every value in your dict.

Don't use `fromkeys` with a mutable value.  Use a dict comprehension:

```
a = {round(x*0.1, 1): [0, 0] for x in range(10)}
```

Or, if you're stuck with 2.6, a fake dict comprehension:

```
a = dict((round(x*0.1, 1), [0, 0]) for x in range(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the dictionary entries reference the same list.  You would be better off creating the dictionary differently:

```
a = {}
for x in range(10):
    a[round(x*0.1,1)] = [0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same list instance as value for all keys. Instead of:

```
a=dict.fromkeys([round(x*0.1,1) for x in range(10)], [0,0])
```

Initialize it like this:

```
a=dict((round(x*0.1,1), [0, 0]) for x in range(10))
```